# Is there a way for me to search or display/link my "Following" list of questions and comments that I am currently following?

Tags: feature-request

I often see interesting questions and answers posted on Stack Overflow and other sites here and those that are particularly interesting, I press <kbd>Follow</kbd>.   I sometimes would like to go back to some of those sites and rather than depending upon having bookmarked it myself, I would like to just pull up a list of questions I've followed and choose from there.  Is there a function for that already that I just haven't noticed?

(Edit Follows)
It has been suggested that I be using bookmarks (or saves) to list those question, but I don't see any way to enter either Bookmarks or Saves when I am reading a question.  The saves lists on my profile in Stack Overflow is empty (Now that I know I have to go to my profile to find THAT)  So it doesn't seem that Following doesn't automatically put an item in the Saves, anyway.  AFAICT.

(Additional Edit)
In all my years on Stack Overflow, I've never noticed that save/star/bookmark icon!  Now I know.  I don't know if it's unwanted redundancy, but perhaps "Save" can be an added option to the "Share Edit Follow.." list after the question as well.

Comment: [Following](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=following) and [Saves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/saves/current/all).